# HackerRank Sherlock and Array performance

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I did this small algorithm to the HackerRank Sherlock and Array test, but this gets timeouts in 2 test cases. These test cases creates huge lists and i couldn't see what is wrong in terms of performance.

This is the problem:

Watson gives Sherlock an array AA of length NN. Then he asks him to determine if there exists an element in the array such that the sum of the elements on its left is equal to the sum of the elements on its right. If there are no elements to the left/right, then the sum is considered to be zero. 
Formally, find an ii, such that, AA1+A+A2...A...Ai-1 =A=Ai+1+A+Ai+2...A...AN.

Input Format 
The first line contains TT, the number of test cases. For each test case, the first line contains NN, the number of elements in the array AA. The second line for each test case contains NN space-separated integers, denoting the array AA.

Output Format 
For each test case print YES if there exists an element in the array, such that the sum of the elements on its left is equal to the sum of the elements on its right; otherwise print NO.

This is my code:

```
for turn in range(int(input())):
    lst_size = int(input())
    has_equal = False

    lst = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))

    if lst_size > 2:

        for i in range(lst_size):
            sumleft = sum(lst[:i])
            sumright = sum(lst[(i+1):])

            if sumleft == sumright:
                has_equal = True
                break

    if has_equal:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: It would help if you explained what the problem is? Also, what kind of inputs exactly are causing the script to timeout

Comment: Hint: the current complexity is O(n**2) but you can reduce it to O(n)

Comment: Check your code indentation, there's no indented block after the for statement in the first line.

Comment: I posted the entire problem, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could improve the code by not doing the sum on every iteration and it worked:

```
for turn in range(int(input())):
      lst_size = int(input())

      has_equal = False

      lst = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))

      sumleft = 0
      total = sum(lst)

      for i in range(1, lst_size):
           sumright = 0
           sumleft += lst[i-1]
           sumright = total - sumleft - lst[i]

           if sumleft == sumright:
               has_equal = True
               break

    if has_equal or lst_size == 1:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a sum costs like an iteration, you have to make it only once and ajust the sum. You can for instance start from the center of the list :

```
def test_list(lst):
    i = len(lst)/2
    sumleft = sum(lst[:i])
    sumright = sum(lst[i+1:])

    if sumleft==sumright:
        print "YES",i

    elif sumleft<sumright:
        print "going right"
        while(True):
            if sumleft==sumright:
                print "YES",i
                break
            if i==len(lst)-1 or sumleft>sumright :
                print "NO",i
                break
            sumleft += lst[i]
            sumright -= lst[i+1]
            i+=1

    else:
        print "going left"
        while(True):

            if sumleft==sumright:
                print "YES",i
                break
            if i==0 or sumleft<sumright :
                print "NO",i
                break
            sumright += lst[i]
            sumleft -= lst[i-1]
            i-=1



lst = [40,1,5,4,6,3,2,1,4,8,7,3,81]
test_list(lst)
```

Result :

```
> going right
> YES 11
```

Comment: I just posted the entire problem, I have to print one line per list in order.

Comment: Then just use this algorithm as a fonction. I read like 10 times the problem and I still don't get what is the shape of the input. But you should be able to make a simple loop adapted to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this in O(n) time and all the test cases got passed.
You can drive the solution equation by using a little bit of mathematics.

Assume we have an array which is the random array {3,7,5,10,2,7,4,2} so, in that, that element exists such that the sum of the left side of all the elements is equal to the sum of the right side all the elements.

I am assuming that element is represented by y and it exists in between somewhere. so some of the left side of the element is represented by x as I said the sum of all the elements towards the left side is equal to the sum of all the elements towards the right side of that element. so right side sum also can be represented by x.So by seeing this, we can easily say the sum of all elements presents inside the array should be equal to x + y + x.

x + y + x = sum of all the elements

2 x + y=sum of all the elements

**2 x = sum of all the elements - y** ---> eq 1

if we have x and y such that this equation holds true. It means, there is one element exist correct because in this equation we have to unknowns x and y. so we have to first get the value of x and y and then will place both the values inside the equation and see whether LHS is equals to RHS or not? LHS equals to RHS it means there is some element exist inside the array where the sum of all the elements towards the left side of the element is equal to the right side of the element. Let’s take one example array.

{3,7,5,10,2,7,4,2}

first, I will calculate the sum of all elements.

sum of all the elements= 3+7+5+10+2+7+4+2 sum of all the elements= 40

replace this in eq 1 then you will get below eq

**2x =40 - y** --> eq 2

as we are not aware of the y but y that's for sure y will belong to any one of the elements which are present inside the array. so will take one element at a time from the array and replace y with that element like that x also. we will take the x value based on y whatever it comes and replace in this question and see whether LHS equals to RHS or not. if we found any such pair of x and y where LHS equals to RHS. It means, we have that element inside the array which holds this criterion true and we will return YES.

for first iteration- {3,7,5,10,2,7,4,2}

y=3, x=0

just replace both values in eq 2 and you can seed

0 is not equal to 37

now move the pointer ahead try this time

y=7, x=0+3=3

just replace both values in eq 2 and you can seed

6 is not equal to 33

....so do the same until you find that element y which satisfy this condition.

now skipping next iterating with y=5 and trying for y=10 know

if y=10 ,x=3+7+5=15

just replace both values in eq 2 and you can seed

30 is equal to 30. It means this the element(y) which we are looking for and where left sum is equal to the right sum.

Here is the code which passes 100% test case.

```
static String balancedSums(List<Integer> arr) {
        int x = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int a : arr) {
            sum += a;
        }

        for (int y : arr) {
            if (2 * x == sum - y) {
                return "YES";
            }
            x = x + y;
        }
        return "NO";

    }
```

Still having doubt you can check out the video tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/xPHJH8RL3mo).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying my luck here and solving it in Python.

The question asks to find an ELEMENT (X) where the sum of elements in an array on the Left of (X) is Equal to the sum of elements on the Right of (X).

In other words, sum of Prefix == sum of Suffix.

What is done here is I took 2 variables that will count elements ONE from Left and another ONE from Right.

2 Variables are...

"count" that counts from Left to Right and ...
"rev_count" that will count from Right to Left.

Another variable "temp" that will store the First Element (0 - based).

I used a while loop to set a condition, that as long as the "temp" variable is not == to the sum of elements, which are counted from RIGHT TO LEFT.

(1) The count will increase to 1...

(2) The rev_count will also increase to 1...decreasing the count FROM RIGHT TO LEFT.
allowing the value of temp to be updated with summing of the elements from LEFT TO RIGHT.

This process is repeated until we get into the IF condition, which gives us the answer if we find the element and "No" if we don't.

If we find the element it is denoted as the element+1, which is [count+1], which in a way is the fulcrum that balances the array.

```
import numpy as np

d = [1, 4, 2, 5]
count = 0
rev_count = 2


temp = d[count]

while temp != sum(d[rev_count::]):
    rev_count += 1
    count += 1
    temp = temp + d[count]

np_array = np.array(d)
item_index = np.where(np_array==d[count+1])

if temp == sum(d[rev_count::]):
    print(d[count+1])
    print(item_index)

else:
    print("No")
```

The finding of element works and the index of the element as well.

Any feedback or critique are welcomed...Thanks for the opportunity.